# How to open an activity on the lock screen after FCM notification

Tags: java, android

How can I open an activity on the lock screen without the user having to click on it? Like for example an alarm or a call.
In my code I can get the FCM notification and if the user clicks on the notification it is possible to open an activity, but I wanted the user not to have to click on it.

FirebaseService.java

```
//--- Notificacao
    public void createNotificationChannel(){
        mNotifyManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);


        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O){

            //create a notification channel
            NotificationChannel notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel(PRIMARY_CHANNEL_ID,
                    "Mascot Notification", NotificationManager
                    .IMPORTANCE_HIGH);

            notificationChannel.enableLights(true);
            notificationChannel.setLightColor(Color.RED);
            notificationChannel.enableVibration(true);
            notificationChannel.setDescription("Notification from Mascot");

            mNotifyManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);

        }

    }

    public void sendNotification(String taskName){

        NotificationCompat.Builder notifyBuilder = getNotificationBuilder(taskName);

        //agora temos que entregar a notificacao
        mNotifyManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notifyBuilder.build());

    }

    public NotificationCompat.Builder getNotificationBuilder(String taskName){

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, TesteActivity.class);
        PendingIntent p = getPendingIntent(NOTIFICATION_ID, intent, getApplicationContext());

        return new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, PRIMARY_CHANNEL_ID)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification_icon)
                .setContentText("titulo teste")
                .setContentIntent(p)
                .setCategory(NotificationCompat.CATEGORY_ALARM)
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
                .setVisibility(NotificationCompat.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC);

    }

    private PendingIntent getPendingIntent(int id, Intent intent, Context context){
        TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(context);
        stackBuilder.addParentStack(intent.getComponent());
        stackBuilder.addNextIntent(intent);

        PendingIntent p = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(id, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        return p;
    }
```

TesteActivity.java

```
public class TesteActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_teste);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O_MR1) {
            setTurnScreenOn(true);
            setShowWhenLocked(true);
            KeyguardManager keyguardManager = (KeyguardManager) getSystemService(Context.KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
            keyguardManager.requestDismissKeyguard(this, null);

        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of `mNotifyManager.notify(` call, which shows your `Notification`, just use `startActivity(..`? you may need also [`WakeLock`](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/wakelock) and `showOnLockScreen` attribute set for this `Activity` in manifest

edit: and [HERE](https://proandroiddev.com/how-to-show-an-activity-on-lock-screen-instead-of-a-notification-ff288d35bfe5) you can find article with exactly your case tutorial

Comment: thanks, apparently it worked out fine. I had to include this as well. intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

Comment: consider upvoting/accepting answer if helpful, good luck! :)